# variables in files not viewed as global by using envir = .GlobalEnv

Tags: r

In **file1.r** we have:

```
foo1 <- function(x, envir = .GlobalEnv){
var1 <- 5
}
```

In file **runme.r**, which is the file we run, we have:

```
source("file1.r")

foo1("some input")

# we ask to print var1
# and receive "object not found"
# although function foo1 is in envir = .GlobalEnv
var1
```

I'm looking for a solution using environments.
Thank you in advance all of you.

Comment: You didn't actually assign `var1` and `var2` to the global environment; you just declared a function parameter `envir`, having a default value of `.GlobalEnv`. You can do something like `assign("var1", 5, envir=envir)` in your function body.

Comment: You are right but var1 maybe some outcome from a procedure and assign cannot be used. That's why I am asking the way to send this outcome to the global environment

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean - can you clarify this with a minimal example?

Comment: At the end of your function ... `return(var1)` you need to return the variable so it outputs.

Comment: For example it could be the outcome of a multiple regression function (lm): fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=mydata)

Comment: Thank you Brandon but I am looking for the an environment solution

Comment: @Apostolos I'm sorry but your objective is still unclear to me. I would suggest that you edit your question and use a different example than `var1 <- 5` because this (apparently) doesn't represent your problem accurately.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood try this. Just let me know how you are calling that function. I gave two ways take which one is suitable for you.

```
foo1 <- function(x){

  assign("var1", 5, envir = .GlobalEnv)

}
foo1(1)

foo2 <- function(){
  assign("var2", 15, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

foo2()

> var1
[1] 5
> var2
[1] 15
>
```

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for the an environment solution. Meanwhile I made the example even more simple

Comment: In place of value(5) you can write whatever you want to make it global. It will work.